# Error al intentar ordenar tablas

Tags: vue.js

Estoy intentando ordenar una tabla de valores en VUE CLI obtenidos a través de una API que hasta ahora funcionaba perfectamente pero que cuando intento realizar dicha acción deja de mostrar cualquier dato.

La consola me indica que 'sort' is undefined. Que estoy haciendo mal?

https://codepen.io/kinatzu/pen/qBdvdOo?editable=true&editors=101

Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Puedes enseñarnos que te devuelve la llamada?

Comment: Bienvenida al sitio, es importante agregues en el cuerpo de la pregunta lo que tratas de realizar, revisa [ask], saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Recuerda que cuando usas la api `fetch`, debes parsear a `json` el response que es también una promesa. entonces quedaría así:

```
mounted() {
  fetch("https://covid-193.p.rapidapi.com/statistics", {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "x-rapidapi-host": "covid-193.p.rapidapi.com",
      "x-rapidapi-key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    }
  })
    .then(json => {
      json.json()
        .then(result => {
          const sortedData = result.sort((a, b) => {
            if (a.cases.total === b.cases.total) return 0
            return a.cases.total < b.cases.total ? 1 : -1
          })
          this.data = sortedData
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Christian. Lo entendí pero aplicando tu código sigue sin funcionarme. No se si fallo al poner algún } o que.

Comment: podrías mostrar almenos 2 items del `result` del request e indicar cual es tu resultado esperado, no estoy seguro si el `sort` que usas está correcto.